# If static friction $F_f$ is a multiple of $F_n$, how can it then point in another direction than $F_n$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

static friction is:

Ff = mu * Fn

So it means, it is just a multiple of the Fn force vector. How is it possible that its always shown in the illustrations in a different direction than the Fn vector?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may be useful.  The *magnitude* of the friction force is proportional to the *magnitude* of the normal force, but the direction is always parallel to the contact surface.  If you look closely at the definitions, you'll see that only the magnitudes are involved.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> static friction is:
>
> Ff = mu * Fn

You need to understand that this equation is for the *maximum possible* static friction force, that is, the static friction force when motion is impending. The actual static friction force is is a variable that is less than or equal to that and matches and opposes the applied force parallel to the surface up to the maximum possible static friction force.

For the 2 kg mass and a coefficient of static friction of 1.00, the maximum possible static friction force is 19.6 N ($μmg$ where g=9.81 m/s$^2$). But since your applied force of 10.8 N is less than the maximum possible static friction force, the actual static friction force is 10.8 N to match the applied force.

> How is it possible that its always shown in the illustrations in a
> different direction than the Fn vector?

Because the direction of the static friction force is always parallel to the surface and opposes the applied force parallel to the surface.

Hope this helps.